# Google search from global sites

Tags: google-search, geolocation

If I search Google from different countries (e.c. google.de, google.co.uk, google.fr, etc.), will they all bring exactly the same search results? Will the order be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It gives priority to local results.

For example if you look for "apple" in google.it, as first result, it gives:

> Apple
>   Apple progetta e crea iPod e iTunes, computer Mac desktop e portatili, il sistema operativo >OS X ei rivoluzionari iPhone e iPad.
>   www.apple.com/it/